# How to optimize this "Time apart" SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to have an easy way to run queries like the following query on my time series data:

"What are the most typical events to take place within seven days of eachother"?

I could do this by utilizing SQL and a Java program, by looking at each row and run a query, which looks up all events seven days earlier or later, but this is not very elegant and performance will be horrible.

I also got help from JNK and Milen A. Radev to write the following SQL. My problem is that when I tested this on 23 million rows, it ran for two hours and stopped because my RamDisk (where I run the PostgreSQL database) was full. Do you have any idea how I could optimize such a query?

```
SELECT a.eventID, b.eventID, COUNT(*)
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b
    ON a.eventID <> b.eventID
WHERE aBS(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (a.thetimeanddate - b.thetimeanddate))) < 5 
GROUP BY a.eventID, b.eventID 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Your query does *not* "look up events seven days earlier or later". It simply returns **all** rows from table a that have a matching row in table be and calculates the difference between two columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are absolutely right. I picked the wrong SQL query. I have updated my question.

Comment: @David: are you sure about the `ON a.eventID <> b.eventID` condition? This does not join corresponding rows and will probably generate a huge result set.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree that this is a very broad join, but I do not know how to make it more restrictive. The final output is reduced using the where clause, but maybe I should move the where clause so it is a part of the join condition?

Comment: @David: are you sure you don't want `ON a.eventID = b.eventID` ?

Comment: @A_horse_with_no_name - he was looking for a query to return different events that happen within a timerange of each other, so we need the inequality in the join condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the problem is that certain functions prevent the RDBMS from being able to infer certain properties of your query and then search any indexes.  (Look up SARGABLE for more info on this.)

This means that the RDBMS is having to process Every combination of events and check the WHERE caluse to see if they are within 5 days of each other.  Every combination equates to 529,000,000,000,000 combinations.  (529 million million is quite a lot.)

If you reform the query to say "WHERE b.thetimeanddate has these properties", then you may find a performance boost.  This will happen if you have an index covering [thetimeanddate] field.  For example...

```
SELECT
  a.eventID,
  b.eventID,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  table a
INNER JOIN
  table b
    ON a.eventID <> b.eventID
WHERE
      b.thetimeanddate >= date_trunc('day', a.thetimeanddate) - INTERVAL '5 days'
  AND b.thetimeanddate <  date_trunc('day', a.thetimeanddate) + INTERVAL '6 days'
GROUP BY
  a.eventID,
  b.eventID
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT
  1000
;
```

The RDBMS should now be able to much more easily make use of any index on the table that covers [thetimeanddate] field.  It now just works out the truncated dates for each of the 29 million events that you have, and checks an index to see how many appear between "this date" and "that date".  Quite possibly a few million times quicker than the alternative...

(I would also be tempted to move the WHERE clause into the ON clause, but only for style purposes.  The performance will be identical.  Remember, the RBDMS compiles these queries, and chooses algorithms and optimisations.  If two queries can be algebraically manipulated in to being the same, they will normally yield the same final execution plan.  [Assuming all the information needed for the manipulation exists in the query, and is not 'just known in your head'.])

**EDIT**

I've also noticed that you're grouping by Both a.eventID and b.eventID, then doing a count.  Assuming the eventID is unique in the table, this would always yield a count of 1...

**EDIT**

Changed +5 to + INTERVAL '5 days'

Comment: This re-factoring May still yield a performance increase without an index.  However, it is highly recommended you create one.  As pointed out, the basic self join yields 529 million million combinations, you need to give the RDBMS a mechanism to selectively reduce the records being checked.  The first part of that is an Index.

Comment: @Dems There actually was never an index in the time column, as I assumed that it could not be used by such a query. The same events can happen many times, hence the need for group by on both. I am getting an error with your query, though: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone - integer

Comment: @David - Highly recommended that you put an index on your time fields.

Comment: @david: What data type is your [thetimeanddate] field?  You just need to make the date_trunc() parts of the example do what you want them to...

Comment: Standard SQL syntax for intervals is `+ INTERVAL '5' DAY`, which matters if you work on multiple platforms. PostgreSQL is a little weird about intervals. For example `+ INTERVAL '5' DAY` and `+ INTERVAL '5' DAYS` evaluate much differently.